# Website Gone error while using Google Chrome on Android devices only?

Tags: android, opencart

My website is turning Gone error while being accessed on android devices, using Google chrome only. I tried many ways but nothing seems working and no clue what's the problem. I am using Opencart 1.5.6.4 with Journal theme and hosted with siteground.

Desperately need help and suggestions from you guys! **please help!**

The error i get

**Gone**
The requested resource 
/is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.

Below is my .htaccess code. Please have a look and suggest if anything is wrong there. Appreciate guys!

```html
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^q-depot.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.q\-depot\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]


#RewriteCond %{http_host} ^q-depot\.net$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://q-depot.com/$1?utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=oldUrl1&utm_campaign=net [R=301,NC,QSA,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
#RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.q-depot\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.q-depot.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
#RewriteCond %{http_host} !^q-depot\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://q-depot.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

# Caching information
# Note: (use A3024000 for 5 weeks or A604800 for 1 week)

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
 
# Set up caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

# 17/2/2015 Jasmine: Remove bad bot

# 2013 UA BLACKLIST [1/3]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(127\.0\.0\.0|localhost) [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (\<|\>|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\!susie|\_irc|\_works|\+select\+|\+union\+|\&lt;\?|1\,\1\,1\,|3gse|4all|4anything|5\.1\;\ xv6875\)|59\.64\.153\.|85\.17\.|88\.0\.106\.|98|a\_browser|a1\ site|abac|abach|abby|aberja|abilon|abont|abot|accept|access|accoo|accoon|aceftp|acme|active|address|adopt|adress|advisor|agent|ahead|aihit|aipbot|alarm|albert|alek|alexa\ toolbar\;\ \(r1\ 1\.5\)|alltop|alma|alot|alpha|america\ online\ browser\ 1\.1|amfi|amfibi|anal|andit|anon|ansearch|answer|answerbus|answerchase|antivirx|apollo|appie|arach|archive|arian|aboutoil|asps|aster|atari|atlocal|atom|atrax|atrop|attrib|autoh|autohot|av\ fetch|avsearch|axod|axon|baboom|baby|back|baid|bali|bandit|barry|basichttp|batch|bdfetch|beat|beaut|become|bee|beij|betabot|biglotron|bilgi|binlar|bison|bitacle|bitly|blaiz|blitz|blogl|blogscope|blogzice|bloob|blow|bord|bond|boris|bost|bot\.ara|botje|botw|bpimage|brand|brok|broth|browseabit|browsex|bruin|bsalsa|bsdseek|built|bulls|bumble|bunny|busca|busi|buy|bwh3|cafek|cafi|camel|cand|captu|casper|catch|ccbot|ccubee|cd34|ceg|cfnetwork|cgichk|cha0s|chang|chaos|char|char\(|chase\ x|check\_http|checker|checkonly|checkprivacy|chek|chill|chttpclient|cipinet|cisco|cita|citeseer|clam|claria|claw|cloak|clshttp|clush|coast|cmsworldmap|code\.com|cogent|coldfusion|coll|collect|comb|combine|commentreader|common|comodo|compan|compatible\-|conc|conduc|contact|control|contype|conv|cool|copi|copy|coral|corn|cosmos|costa|cowbot|cr4nk|craft|cralwer|crank|crap|crawler0|crazy|cres|cs\-cz|cshttp|cuill|CURI|curl|curry|custo|cute|cyber|cz3|czx|daily|dalvik|daobot|dark|darwin|data|daten|dcbot|dcs|dds\ explorer|deep|deps|detect|dex|diam|diavol|diibot|dillo|ding|disc|disp|ditto|dlc|doco|dotbot|drag|drec|dsdl|dsok|dts|duck|dumb|eag|earn|earthcom|easydl|ebin|echo|edco|egoto|elnsb5|email|emer|empas|encyclo|enfi|enhan|enterprise\_search|envolk|erck|erocr|eventax|evere|evil|ewh|exac|exploit|expre|extra|eyen|fang|fast|fastbug|faxo|fdse|feed24|feeddisc|feedfinder|feedhub|fetch|filan|fileboo|fimap|find|firebat|firedownload\/1\.2pre\ firefox\/3\.6|firefox\/0|firs|flam|flash|flexum|flicky|flip|fly|focus|fooky|forum|forv|fost|foto|foun|fount|foxy\/1\;|free|friend|frontpage|fuck|fuer|futile|fyber|gais|galbot|gbpl|gecko\/2001|gecko\/2002|gecko\/2006|gecko\/2009042316|gener|geni|geo|geona|geth|getr|getw|ggl|gira|gluc|gnome|go\!zilla|goforit|goldfire|gonzo|google\ wireless|gosearch|got\-it|gozilla|grab|graf|greg|grub|grup|gsa\-cra|gsearch|gt\:\:www|guidebot|guruji|gyps|haha|hailo|harv|hash|hatena|hax|head|helm|herit|heritrix|hgre|hippo|hloader|hmse|hmview|holm|holy|hotbar\ 4\.4\.5\.0|hpprint|href\s|httpclient|httpconnect|httplib|httrack|human|huron|hverify|hybrid|hyper|ia_archiver|iaskspi|ibm\ evv|iccra|ichiro|icopy|ics\)|ida|ie\/5\.0|ieauto|iempt|iexplore\.exe|ilium|ilse|iltrov|indexer|indy|ineturl|infonav|innerpr|inspect|insuran|intellig|interget|internet\_explorer|internet\x|intraf|ip2|ipsel|irlbot|isc\_sys|isilo|isrccrawler|isspi|jady|jaka|jam|jenn|jet|jiro|jobo|joc|jupit|just|jyx|jyxo|kash|kazo|kbee|kenjin|kernel|keywo|kfsw|kkma|kmc|know|kosmix|krae|krug|ksibot|ktxn|kum|labs|lanshan|lapo|larbin|leech|lets|lexi|lexxe|libby|libcrawl|libcurl|libfetch|libweb|light|linc|lingue|linkcheck|linklint|linkman|lint|list|litefeeds|livedoor|livejournal|liveup|lmq|loader|locu|london|lone|loop|lork|lth\_|lwp|mac\_f|magi|magp|mail\.ru|main|majest|mam|mama|mana|marketwire|masc|mass|mata|mvi|mcbot|mecha|mechanize|mediapartners|metadata|metalogger|metaspin|metauri|mete|mib\/2\.2|microsoft\.url|microsoft\_internet\_explorer|mido|miggi|miix|mindjet|mindman|miner|mips|mira|mire|miss|mist|mizz|mj12|mlbot|mlm|mnog|moge|moje|mooz|more|mouse|mozdex) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (\<|\>|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\!susie|\_irc|\_works|\+select\+|\+union\+|\&lt;\?|1\,\1\,1\,|3gse|4all|4anything|5\.1\;\ xv6875\)|59\.64\.153\.|85\.17\.|88\.0\.106\.|98|a\_browser|a1\ site|abac|abach|abby|aberja|abilon|abont|abot|accept|access|accoo|accoon|aceftp|acme|active|address|adopt|adress|advisor|agent|ahead|aihit|aipbot|alarm|albert|alek|alexa\ toolbar\;\ \(r1\ 1\.5\)|alltop|alma|alot|alpha|america\ online\ browser\ 1\.1|amfi|amfibi|anal|andit|anon|ansearch|answer|answerbus|answerchase|antivirx|apollo|appie|arach|archive|arian|aboutoil|asps|aster|atari|atlocal|atom|atrax|atrop|attrib|autoh|autohot|av\ fetch|avsearch|axod|axon|baboom|baby|back|baid|bali|bandit|barry|basichttp|batch|bdfetch|beat|beaut|become|bee|beij|betabot|biglotron|bilgi|binlar|bison|bitacle|bitly|blaiz|blitz|blogl|blogscope|blogzice|bloob|blow|bord|bond|boris|bost|bot\.ara|botje|botw|bpimage|brand|brok|broth|browseabit|browsex|bruin|bsalsa|bsdseek|built|bulls|bumble|bunny|busca|busi|buy|bwh3|cafek|cafi|camel|cand|captu|casper|catch|ccbot|ccubee|cd34|ceg|cfnetwork|cgichk|cha0s|chang|chaos|char|char\(|chase\ x|check\_http|checker|checkonly|checkprivacy|chek|chill|chttpclient|cipinet|cisco|cita|citeseer|clam|claria|claw|cloak|clshttp|clush|coast|cmsworldmap|code\.com|cogent|coldfusion|coll|collect|comb|combine|commentreader|common|comodo|compan|compatible\-|conc|conduc|contact|control|contype|conv|cool|copi|copy|coral|corn|cosmos|costa|cowbot|cr4nk|craft|cralwer|crank|crap|crawler0|crazy|cres|cs\-cz|cshttp|cuill|CURI|curl|curry|custo|cute|cyber|cz3|czx|daily|dalvik|daobot|dark|darwin|data|daten|dcbot|dcs|dds\ explorer|deep|deps|detect|dex|diam|diavol|diibot|dillo|ding|disc|disp|ditto|dlc|doco|dotbot|drag|drec|dsdl|dsok|dts|duck|dumb|eag|earn|earthcom|easydl|ebin|echo|edco|egoto|elnsb5|email|emer|empas|encyclo|enfi|enhan|enterprise\_search|envolk|erck|erocr|eventax|evere|evil|ewh|exac|exploit|expre|extra|eyen|fang|fast|fastbug|faxo|fdse|feed24|feeddisc|feedfinder|feedhub|fetch|filan|fileboo|fimap|find|firebat|firedownload\/1\.2pre\ firefox\/3\.6|firefox\/0|firs|flam|flash|flexum|flicky|flip|fly|focus|fooky|forum|forv|fost|foto|foun|fount|foxy\/1\;|free|friend|frontpage|fuck|fuer|futile|fyber|gais|galbot|gbpl|gecko\/2001|gecko\/2002|gecko\/2006|gecko\/2009042316|gener|geni|geo|geona|geth|getr|getw|ggl|gira|gluc|gnome|go\!zilla|goforit|goldfire|gonzo|gosearch|got\-it|gozilla|grab|graf|greg|grub|grup|gsa\-cra|gsearch|gt\:\:www|guidebot|guruji|gyps|haha|hailo|harv|hash|hatena|hax|head|helm|herit|heritrix|hgre|hippo|hloader|hmse|hmview|holm|holy|hotbar\ 4\.4\.5\.0|hpprint|href\s|httpclient|httpconnect|httplib|httrack|human|huron|hverify|hybrid|hyper|ia_archiver|iaskspi|ibm\ evv|iccra|ichiro|icopy|ics\)|ida|ie\/5\.0|ieauto|iempt|iexplore\.exe|ilium|ilse|iltrov|indexer|indy|ineturl|infonav|innerpr|inspect|insuran|intellig|interget|internet\_explorer|internet\x|intraf|ip2|ipsel|irlbot|isc\_sys|isilo|isrccrawler|isspi|jady|jaka|jam|jenn|jet|jiro|jobo|joc|jupit|just|jyx|jyxo|kash|kazo|kbee|kenjin|kernel|keywo|kfsw|kkma|kmc|know|kosmix|krae|krug|ksibot|ktxn|kum|labs|lanshan|lapo|larbin|leech|lets|lexi|lexxe|libby|libcrawl|libcurl|libfetch|libweb|light|linc|lingue|linkcheck|linklint|linkman|lint|list|litefeeds|livedoor|livejournal|liveup|lmq|loader|locu|london|lone|loop|lork|lth\_|lwp|mac\_f|magi|magp|mail\.ru|main|majest|mam|mama|mana|marketwire|masc|mass|mata|mvi|mcbot|mecha|mechanize|mediapartners|metadata|metalogger|metaspin|metauri|mete|mib\/2\.2|microsoft\.url|microsoft\_internet\_explorer|mido|miggi|miix|mindjet|mindman|miner|mips|mira|mire|miss|mist|mizz|mj12|mlbot|mlm|mnog|moge|moje|mooz|more|mouse|mozdex) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* - [G]
</IfModule>

# 2013 UA BLACKLIST [2/3]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla\/0|mozilla\/1|mozilla\/4\.61\ \[en\]|mozilla\/firefox|mpf|msie\ 2|msie\ 3|msie\ 4|msie\ 5|msie\ 6\.0\-|msie\ 6\.0b|msie\ 7\.0a1\;|msie\ 7\.0b\;|msie6xpv1|msiecrawler|msnbot\-media|msnbot\-products|msnptc|msproxy|msrbot|musc|mvac|mwm|my\_age|myapp|mydog|myeng|myie2|mysearch|myurl|nag|name|naver|navr|near|netants|netcach|netcrawl|netfront|netinfo|netmech|netsp|netx|netz|neural|neut|newsbreak|newsgatorinbox|newsrob|newt|next|ng\-s|ng\/2|nice|nikto|nimb|ninja|ninte|nog|noko|nomad|norb|note|npbot|nuse|nutch|nutex|nwsp|obje|ocel|octo|odi3|oegp|offby|offline|omea|omg|omhttp|onfo|onyx|openf|openssl|openu|opera\ 2|opera\ 3|opera\ 4|opera\ 5|opera\ 6|opera\ 7|orac|orbit|oreg|osis|our|outf|owl|p3p\_|page2rss|pagefet|pansci|parser|patw|pavu|pb2pb|pcbrow|pear|peer|pepe|perfect|perl|petit|phoenix\/0\.|phras|picalo|piff|pig|pingd|pipe|pirs|plag|planet|plant|platform|playstation|plesk|pluck|plukkie|poe\-com|poirot|pomp|post|postrank|powerset|preload|press|privoxy|probe|program\_shareware|protect|protocol|prowl|proxie|proxy|psbot|pubsub|puf|pulse|punit|purebot|purity|pyq|pyth|query|quest|qweer|radian|rambler|ramp|rapid|rawdog|rawgrunt|reap|reeder|refresh|reget|relevare|repo|requ|request|rese|retrieve|rip|rix|rma|roboz|rocket|rogue|rpt\-http|rsscache|ruby|ruff|rufus|rv\:0\.9\.7\)|salt|sample|sauger|savvy|sbcyds|sbider|sblog|sbp|scagent|scan|scej\_|sched|schizo|schlong|schmo|scorp|scott|scout|scrawl|screen|screenshot|script|seamonkey\/1\.5a|search17|searchbot|searchme|sega|semto|sensis|seop|seopro|sept|sezn|seznam|share|sharp|shaz|shell|shelo|sherl|shim|shopwiki|silurian|simple|simplepie|siph|sitekiosk|sitescan|sitevigil|sitex|skam|skimp|skygrid|sledink|sleip|slide|sly|smag|smurf|snag|snapbot|snapshot|snif|snip|snoop|sock|socsci|sogou|sohu|solr|some|soso|spad|span|spbot|speed|sphere|spin|sproose|spurl|sputnik|spyder|squi|sqwid|sqworm|ssm\_ag|stack|stamp|statbot|state|steel|stilo|strateg|stress|strip|style|subot|such|suck|sume|sunos\ 5\.7|sunrise|superbot|superbro|supervi|surf4me|surfbot|survey|susi|suza|suzu|sweep|swish|sygol|synapse|sync2it|systems|szukacz|tagger|tagoo|tagyu|take|talkro|tamu|tandem|tarantula|tbot|tcf|tcs\/1|teamsoft|tecomi|teesoft|teleport|telesoft|tencent|terrawiz|test|texnut|thomas|tiehttp|timebot|timely|tipp|tiscali|titan|tmcrawler|tmhtload|tocrawl|todobr|tongco|toolbar\;\ \(r1|topic|topyx|torrent|track|translate|traveler|treeview|tricus|trivia|trivial|true|tunnel|turing|turnitin|tutorgig|twat|tweak|twice|tygo|ubee|uchoo|ultraseek|unavail|unf|universal|unknown|upg1|urlbase|urllib|urly|user\-agent\:|useragent|usyd|vagabo|valet|vamp|vci|veri\~li|verif|versus|via|vikspider|virtual|visual|void|voyager|vsyn|w0000t|w3search|walhello|walker|wand|waol|watch|wavefire|wbdbot|weather|web\.ima|web2mal|webarchive|webbot|webcat|webcor|webcorp|webcrawl|webdat|webdup|webgo|webind|webis|webitpr|weblea|webmin|webmoney|webp|webql|webrobot|webster|websurf|webtre|webvac|webzip|wells|wep\_s|wget|whiz|widow|win67|windows\-rss|windows\ 2000|windows\ 3|windows\ 95|windows\ 98|windows\ ce|windows\ me|winht|winodws|wish|wizz|worio|works|world|worth|wwwc|wwwo|wwwster|xaldon|xbot|xenu|xirq|y\!tunnel|yacy|yahoo\-mmaudvid|yahooseeker|yahooysmcm|yamm|yand|yandex|yang|yoono|yori|yotta|yplus\ |ytunnel|zade|zagre|zeal|zebot|zerx|zeus|zhuaxia|zipcode|zixy|zmao|zmeu|zune) [NC]
# RewriteRule .* - [G]
</IfModule>

# 2013 UA BLACKLIST [3/3] (pentag0)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (black\ hole|titan|webstripper|netmechanic|cherrypicker|emailcollector|emailsiphon|webbandit|emailwolf|extractorpro|copyrightcheck|crescent|wget|sitesnagger|prowebwalker|cheesebot|teleport|teleportpro|miixpc|telesoft|website\ quester|webzip|moget/2\.1|webzip/4\.0|websauger|webcopier|netants|mister\ pix|webauto|thenomad|www-collector-e|rma|libweb/clshttp|asterias|httplib|turingos|spanner|infonavirobot|harvest/1\.5|bullseye/1\.0|mozilla/4\.0\ \(compatible;\ bullseye;\ windows\ 95\)|crescent\ internet\ toolpak\ http\ ole\ control\ v\.1\.0|cherrypickerse/1\.0|cherrypicker\ /1\.0|webbandit/3\.50|nicerspro|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 5\.01\.4511|dittospyder|foobot|webmasterworldforumbot|spankbot|botalot|lwp-trivial/1\.34|lwp-trivial|wget/1\.6|bunnyslippers|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 6\.00\.8169|urly\ warning|wget/1\.5\.3|linkwalker|cosmos|moget|hloader|humanlinks|linkextractorpro|offline\ explorer|mata\ hari|lexibot|web\ image\ collector|the\ intraformant|true_robot/1\.0|true_robot|blowfish/1\.0|jennybot|miixpc/4\.2|builtbottough|propowerbot/2\.14|backdoorbot/1\.0|tocrawl/urldispatcher|webenhancer|tighttwatbot|suzuran|vci\ webviewer\ vci\ webviewer\ win32|vci|szukacz/1\.4|queryn\ metasearch|openfind\ data\ gathere|openfind|xenu\'s\ link\ sleuth\ 1\.1c|xenu's|zeus|repomonkey\ bait\ &\ tackle/v1\.01|repomonkey|zeus\ 32297\ webster\ pro\ v2\.9\ win32|webster\ pro|erocrawler|linkscan/8\.1a\ unix|keyword\ density/0\.9|kenjin\ spider|cegbfeieh) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* - [G]
</IfModule>

# END 17/2/2015 Jasmine: Remove bad bot

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `.htaccess` and remove any problematic rules.

Comment: i am going to post my .htaccess code in my question above, hope you are kind enough to have a quick look for a possible fault. Appreciate your help bro!

Comment: You should start by removing all the lines between `# 17/2/2015 Jasmine: Remove bad bot` and `# END 17/2/2015 Jasmine: Remove bad bot`. I pretty sure in there is your problem.

Comment: you really made my day man. You rock :) at last i got rid of this problem and website works as charm on Goolge chrome using Android devices. Many thanks man - really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you have time to search further, you can also try removing one by one these rules to see which one is the problematic ;)

Comment: well issue is solved so not much worth bothering now but anyway will try it out. Thanks a lot!